# $Z_p$ acts on a group $G$ by automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A=Z_p$ act on $G$ by automorphism,

It is well known that if this action is fixed point free then $G$ is nilpotent i.e. if $C_G(A)=1$ then $G$ is nilpotent by Thomsan.

I wonder Is there any known result for $C_G(A)\neq 1$ ? Any reference is welcome.

Comment: I think this is much too vague, and you need to ask a more directed question. Any group with a non-central element of order $p$ admits such an automorphism i.e. the inner automorphism induced by this element.

Comment: You are right Derek but I expect another condition instead of fixed point free condition. Since i do know this condition, i could not be sepesific.